# VSCode and Java Setup: No compatible Jar

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm setting up Java within *VSCode* and just can't seem to get the JREs correct. Can someone please lend a pair of eyes and point out what I'm missing?

**2 errors I'm seeing:**

1. *Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.8. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.*
2. *The compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a JRE 11 is used*

**OS**: Windows 10

**Java version installed**: JDK 11 (version 11.0.2)

**Environment Variables**:

*`JAVA_HOME`* > C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12

*`MAVEN_HOME`* > C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.2

*PATH* > `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin`

**POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>sqa.tan</groupId>
  <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>automation</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

<properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev20200919-1.31.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>v2-rev20200213-1.31.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.31.5</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
    <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
          <configuration>
             <source>1.8</source>
             <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

***Screenshot of a few jars in the JRE System Library***

[image: Screenshot of a few jars in the JRE System Library]

Comment: You can use intellij idea community version for java coding. It is good for fast development. Mostly configuration is working easily in this IDE

Comment: @RajeshPatel Yes, so I've been told, but I would like to do this in VSCode for my own purposes and understanding how to set this up. Thank you for your input.

Comment: FYI: [*Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code*](https://inside.java/2023/10/18/announcing-vscode-extension/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have specified **JAVA 1.8** in your POM file but you have **Java 11** installed on your system.

Make the below changes to the POM file:

**Replace:**

```
<properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

**To,**

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target> 
</properties>
```

Also, **replace**

```
  <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
  </configuration>
```

**To,**

```
  <configuration>
     <source>11</source>
     <target>11</target>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Hello @allstarlok I'm going to give this a try and see what happens. Thank you for chiming in.

Comment: Wow, that's what I was missing. Thank you so much @allstarlok. I have a follow up question about this.  For the properties and configuration I kept changing it to `11.0.2` because looking my Command Line, that's the Java version I'm using. But it works putting `11` as you said. Is there a POM resource you know of so I can lookup how POM files work?

Comment: @foragerEngineer you can refer to the official website [link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#:~:text=A%20Project%20Object%20Model%20or,default%20values%20for%20most%20projects.)
or [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-tutorial.html) 
They are a lot of things Maven is capable of like building, testing, deployment. Just play with it you will learn it.

Comment: thank you very much for the links (bookmarked). Much appreciated!